# Retrieve unqiue value using ng-option with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My html file:

```
 <html ng-app='camListApp'>
 <div ng-controller="Hello">
 <h3>Search:</h3><br>
 <select ng-model="searchBox" ng-options="x.cameraid as x.cameraid for x in records| unique:'cameraid'">
 <option value="">{{x.cameraid}}</option>
 </select>
```

My current js file:

```
 var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []);
 camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
 camListApp.filter('unique', function() {
      return function(input, key) {
          var unique = {};
          var uniqueList = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
              if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                  unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                  uniqueList.push(input[i]);
              }
          }
          return uniqueList;
      };
      });

   $scope.custom = true;
   $scope.toggleCustom = function() {
   $scope.custom = ! $scope.custom;
 };

 $http.get('http://localhost:8081/camera/list').then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
        $scope.records= response.data; 
    });
 }]);
```

My json data on web service:

```
[{"id":23,"cameraid":"000000006f4280af","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:27","filename":"452c5d867b563e937d44d48ebc326c7a"},
{"id":24,"cameraid":"000000006f4280af","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:27","filename":"ee90428e4e0c19ba9858285398bf4fbb"},
{"id":25,"cameraid":"000000006f4280af","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:28","filename":"c9a4fb339f6981ffd679937724167de8"},
{"id":26,"cameraid":"000000006f4280af","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:28","filename":"a1df86417d958e670750cf8172a2b7dd"}
```

Why i can't display my cameraid unique value "000000006f4280af" on my dropdownlist? I used ng-option to display unique value for my cameraid. Anyone can help me solve this?

Comment: Read the `ng-options` docs. You aren't using it properly for array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the expected result,use below option

ng-options -x.cameraid for x in records| unique:'cameraid  (syntax is wrong in the post)

```
          <div ng-app="camListApp" ng-controller="Hello">
      <select ng-model="searchBox" ng-options="x.cameraid as x.cameraid for x in records| unique:'cameraid'">
      <option value="">{{x.cameraid}}</option>
      </select>
      </div>
```

And create filter in your js file as below

```
        camListApp.filter('unique', function() {
        return function(input, key) {
            var unique = {};
            var uniqueList = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                    unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                    uniqueList.push(input[i]);
                }
            }
            return uniqueList;
        };
    });
```

Codepen url - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dXXzLY for reference.

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/unpr?p0=uniqueFilterProvider%20%3C-%20uniqueFilter i got this error

Comment: Yea i implement into my Js file

Comment: Place camListApp.filter code below var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []);

Comment: Now i having this error : Error: input is undefined

Comment: Naga Sai, is it possible u help me with this question too. url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852298/how-to-retrieve-image-from-a-web-server-url-path-with-angularjs