# How to retrieve image from a web server url path to angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve images from my web server (on port 9100) to display on my angularJS page.

I wanted to display the image in the particular cell in my table.

Example like: "04080b363fb9d8fe825c7c664bb7a38d.png" image will be shown on the "04080b363fb9d8fe825c7c664bb7a38d.png" table when I click on the "view" button.

My folder from web server apache:
[image: Web Server Folder]

My GUI using angularJS:
[image: angularJS GUI]

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="camListApp">
<head>

<style>
#myDIV {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
right: 20px;
top: 90px;
}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
 </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js">   </script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>

<title>Image viewers</title>
</head>

 <body>
 <div ng-controller="Hello">
 <h3>Search:</h3><br>
<select ng-model="searchBox.cameraid" style="width:25%">
  <option ng-repeat="x in records | unique:'cameraid'" value=" {{x.cameraid}}">{{x.cameraid}}</option>
  </select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 <table style="width:55%">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>CamID</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>View Image</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr ng-repeat="record in records | filter:searchBox | orderBy:'+timestamp'">

        <td>{{record.cameraid}}</td>
        <td>{{record.timestamp}}</td>
         <td>{{record.filename}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="toggleCustom()" onclick="myFunction()">View</button></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <span id="myDIV" ng-hide="custom">
   <img ng-src="" width="300" height="300">
    </span>
    <span ng-show="custom"></span>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.position = "absolute";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My js file:

```
var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []);
camListApp.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var unique = {};
        var uniqueList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    };
  });
  camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){


  $scope.custom = true;
  $scope.toggleCustom = function() {
   $scope.custom = ! $scope.custom;

 };
 $http.get('http://localhost:8081/camera/list').then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
        $scope.records= response.data; 
    });
  }]);
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: are you getting the data response?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN i haven't try to retrieve the image from my folder to angularjs. Because i got no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the expected result, i have used few sample images with the assumption that the data from the backend will be in the format as below

```
 $scope.records=[{"id":23,"cameraid":"001","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:27","filename":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"},
```

{"id":24,"cameraid":"002","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:28","filename":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg"},
{"id":25,"cameraid":"003","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:28","filename":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg"},
{"id":26,"cameraid":"003","timestamp":"2016/06/15 17:28","filename":"http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg"}]

Codepen URL - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jrMboq for reference.

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks Alvin Wee ...vote my answer when possible for you :)

Comment: Do you know how to enlarge the image when you click on the image?

Comment: Alvin, then this should be another question :)

Comment: Hi naga sai , this is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914561/how-to-zoom-image-with-angularjs