# How to zoom image with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i zoom the image when i click on the image itself using angularJS. I cant happen to do it when i using this website given: https://github.com/owlsomely/angular-image-zoom?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation . Anyone can help?

My js file:

```
var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

camListApp.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var unique = {};
        var uniqueList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    };
});
camListApp.controller("Hello", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){ 

$scope.custom = true;
$scope.toggleCustom = function(url) {
    $scope.custom = ! $scope.custom;
     $scope.imageView = url;

};



$http.get('http://localhost:8082/camera/list').then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
        $scope.records= response.data; 
    });
 }]);
```

My html file:

```
 <div ng-controller="Hello" class="col-xs-12">


 <b>Search:</b><br>

<input type = "text" ng-model="searchBox" uib-typeahead="state.cameraid as state.cameraid for state in records | filter:searchBox | limitTo:8 | unique:'cameraid'">


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 <table border = 1 class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width:45%">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th><center>CamID</th></center>
        <th><center>Timestamp</th></center>
        <th><center>View Image</center></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="record in records | filter:searchBox | orderBy:'+timestamp'">

        <td>{{record.cameraid}}</td>
        <td>{{record.timestamp}}</td>
        <td><center> <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleCustom(record.filename)" onclick="myFunction()">View</center></button></td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>

   <span id="myDIV" ng-hide="custom">
   <img ng-src="http://localhost:9100/Images/{{imageView}}.png" image-zoom width="500" height="400">
    </span>

    <!--<span ng-hide="custom">To:
        <input type="text" id="to" />
    </span>-->
    <span ng-show="custom"></span>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.position = "absolute";
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try https://github.com/igorlino/angular-elevatezoom-plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created ng-click on image

HTML

```
    <span id="myDIV" ng-hide="custom">
   <img id="view" ng-src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/{{imageView}}" width="300" height="300" ng-click="zoom()">
    </span>
```

JS

```
 $scope.zoom = function() {
    var imageId = document.getElementById('view');
    if(imageId.style.width == "400px"){
    imageId.style.width = "300px";
    imageId.style.height = "300px";
    }else{
     imageId.style.width = "400px";
    imageId.style.height = "400px";  
    }
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jrMzER

Comment: onclick , image size increases and on second click to resumes to old size.Hope this works for you :)

Comment: You know how to do modal bootstrap ui? like when u click on the view button then display the modal with the image.

Comment: Hi naga, right now i need display my image on the modal ui instead of displaying beside my table. Url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958359/image-does-not-display-in-modal-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

my simple directive to increase the image reduction and image movement. I hope will be useful to you.

```
  (function () {
        angular
            .module('app')
            .directive('zoom', [function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                        var img = elem[0];
                        $(img).css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "top": "0",
                            "bottom": "0",
                            "left": "0",
                            "right": "0",
                            "margin": "auto",
                            "padding-left": "1px",
                            "padding-right": "1px",
                            "padding-top": "1px",
                            "padding-bottom": "1px",
                            "-webkit - user - select": "none",
                            "-webkit - user - drag": "none"
                        });
                        var imageContainer = img.parentNode.parentNode;
                        $(imageContainer).css({
                            "text-align": "center",
                            "margin": "0",
                            "padding": "0",
                            "height": "100%",
                            "max- height": "100%",
                            "width": "100%",
                            "background-color": "#000",
                            "overflow": "hidden",
                            "-webkit - user - select": "none",
                            "cursor": "context - menu",
                        });
                        var parent = img.parentNode;
                        $(parent).css({
                            "width": "100%",
                            "height": "auto",
                            "margin": 0,
                            "padding": 0,
                            "display": "-webkit - box",
                            "-webkit - box - pack": "center",
                            "-webkit - box - align": "center",
                            "z-index": "5"
                        });
                        var currentScale = 1;
                        var currentRotation = 90
                        let transformOriginX = 0, transformOriginY = 0;
                        let translateX = 0, translateY = 0;
                        function setTransformOrigin() {
                            let imgRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                            let parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
                            let visibleWidth = (imgRect.width > parent.offsetWidth) ? imgRect.left + parentRect.width : imgRect.width;
                            let visibleHeight = (imgRect.height > parent.offsetHeight) ? imgRect.top + parentRect.height : imgRect.height;
                            let beginX = parentRect.right - visibleWidth, beginY = parentRect.bottom - visibleHeight;
                            let endX = beginX + visibleWidth, endY = beginY + visibleHeight;
                            let midX = beginX + ((endX - beginX) / 2), midY = beginY + ((endY - beginY) / 2);
                           // if (midY > imageContainer.clientHeight / 2) midY = imageContainer.clientHeight / 2;
                            //if (midX > imageContainer.clientWidth / 2) midX = imageContainer.clientWidth / 2;
                            if (midY > imageContainer.clientHeight / 2) { parent.style.transformOrigin = midX + 'px ' + midY + 'px' } else {
                                parent.style.transformOrigin = midX + 'px ' + imageContainer.clientHeight / 2 + 'px'
                            }
                        }
                        function scaleImage(scale, event) {

                            img.style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ') ' + 'rotate(' + (currentRotation - 90) + 'deg)';
                            if (scale < currentScale) {
                                let imgRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                                let imageContainerRect = imageContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
                                if (parent.style.transform.match('translate')) {
                                    let parentTransform = parent.style.transform.replace('translate(', '').replace(')', '').split(', ');
                                    let moveX = parentTransform[0].replace('px', ''), moveY = parentTransform[1].replace('px', '');
                                    if ((imageContainerRect.right - imgRect.right) > 0 || (imageContainerRect.left - imgRect.left) < 0) {
                                        let moveBy = ((imageContainerRect.right - imgRect.right) > 0) ? (imageContainerRect.right - imgRect.right) : (imageContainerRect.left - imgRect.left);
                                        moveX = (imgRect.width > parent.offsetWidth) ? (parseFloat(parentTransform[0]) + moveBy) : 0;
                                        transformOriginX = (transformOriginX - moveBy);
                                    }
                                    if ((imageContainerRect.bottom - imgRect.bottom) > 0 || (imageContainerRect.top - imgRect.top) < 0) {
                                        let moveBy = ((imageContainerRect.bottom - imgRect.bottom) > 0) ? (imageContainerRect.bottom - imgRect.bottom) : (imageContainerRect.top - imgRect.top);
                                        moveY = (imgRect.height > parent.offsetHeight) ? (parseFloat(parentTransform[1]) + moveBy) : 0;
                                        transformOriginY = (transformOriginY + moveBy);
                                    }
                                    if (scale <= 1) { translateX = 0; translateY = 0; }
                                    parent.style.transformOrigin = transformOriginX + 'px ' + transformOriginY + 'px';
                               }
                            }
                            currentScale = scale;
                            let imgRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                            let parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
                            let overflow_horizontal = (imgRect.width > parent.offsetWidth ? true : false);
                            let overflow_vertical = (imgRect.height > parent.offsetHeight ? true : false);
                            let startX = event.pageX - translateX, startY = event.pageY - translateY;
                            let max_left = parentRect.left - imgRect.left;
                            let max_top = parentRect.top - imgRect.top;
                            var evt = window.event;
                            translateX = (Math.abs(evt.pageX - startX) >= max_left ? (max_left * Math.sign(evt.pageX - startX)) : (evt.pageX - startX));
                            translateY = (Math.abs(evt.pageY - startY) >= max_top ? (max_top * Math.sign(evt.pageY - startY)) : (evt.pageY - startY));
                            translateX = overflow_horizontal ? translateX : 0, translateY = overflow_vertical ? translateY : 0;
                            if ((translateX != 0) && (translateY != 0)) {
                                if (translateY > imageContainer.clientHeight/2) { parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + translateY + 'px)' } else {
                                    parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + imageContainer.clientHeight / 2+'px)'
                                }
                            } else {
                                parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = ''
                            };
                            return false;
                        }

                        function tap() {
                            let imgRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                            let parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
                            let overflow_horizontal = (imgRect.width > parent.offsetWidth ? true : false);
                            let overflow_vertical = (imgRect.height > parent.offsetHeight ? true : false);
                            let startX = event.pageX - translateX, startY = event.pageY - translateY;
                            let max_left = parentRect.left - imgRect.left;
                            let max_top = parentRect.top - imgRect.top;
                            var evt = window.event;
                            translateX = (Math.abs(evt.pageX - startX) >= max_left ? (max_left * Math.sign(evt.pageX - startX)) : (evt.pageX - startX));
                            translateY = (Math.abs(evt.pageY - startY) >= max_top ? (max_top * Math.sign(evt.pageY - startY)) : (evt.pageY - startY));
                            translateX = overflow_horizontal ? translateX : 0, translateY = overflow_vertical ? translateY : 0;
                            if ((translateX != 0) && (translateY != 0)) {
                                if (translateY > imageContainer.clientHeight / 2) {
                                    parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + translateY + 'px)'
                                } else {
                                    parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + imageContainer.clientHeight / 2+ 'px)'
                                }
                            } else {
                                parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = ''
                            };
                        }
                        function makeDraggable(event) {

                            parent = img.parentNode;
                            imageContainer = img.parentNode.parentNode;
                            $(parent).css({

                                "display": "-webkit - box",
                                "-webkit - box - pack": "center",
                                "-webkit - box - align": "center",
                                "z-index": "5"
                            });
                            $(imageContainer).css({
                                "text-align": "center",
                                "margin": "0",
                                "padding": "0",                            
                                "overflow": "hidden",
                                "-webkit - user - select": "none",
                                "cursor": "context - menu",
                            });
                            let imgRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                            let parentRect =parent.getBoundingClientRect();
                            let overflow_horizontal = (imgRect.width > parent.offsetWidth ? true : false);
                            let overflow_vertical = (imgRect.height > parent.offsetHeight ? true : false);
                            let startX = event.pageX - translateX, startY = event.pageY - translateY;
                            let max_left = parentRect.left - imgRect.left;
                            let max_top = parentRect.top - imgRect.top;

                            window.onmousemove = function (evt) {
                                if (evt == null) { evt = window.event; }
                                translateX = (Math.abs(evt.pageX - startX) >= max_left ? (max_left * Math.sign(evt.pageX - startX)) : (evt.pageX - startX));
                                translateY = (Math.abs(evt.pageY - startY) >= max_top ? (max_top * Math.sign(evt.pageY - startY)) : (evt.pageY - startY));
                                translateX = overflow_horizontal ? translateX : 0, translateY = overflow_vertical ? translateY : 0;
                                if ((translateX != 0) && (translateY != 0)) {
                                    if (translateY > imageContainer.clientHeight) {
                                        parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + translateY + 'px)'
                                    } else {
                                       parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + translateX + 'px, ' + imageContainer.clientHeight / 2+ 'px)'
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    parent.style['-webkit-transform'] = ''
                                };
                                return false;
                            }

                            window.onmouseup = function (evt) {
                                setTransformOrigin();
                                window.onmousemove = null;
                            }

                            return false;
                        };
                        img.addEventListener('mousedown', function () { makeDraggable(event); });
                              elem.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
                            var img = e.currentTarget.style.width;
                            var scaleX = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().width / e.currentTarget.offsetWidth;
                            var w = "";
                            var resW = "";
                            var resL = "";
                            var resT = "";
                            var zValue = 1.2;
                            var newScale = scaleX * zValue;
                            var newScale = "scale(1)";
                            var val = parseInt(w.replace('%', ''));
                            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
                                newScale = scaleX * zValue;
                            }
                            else {
                                if ((scaleX / zValue) > 1) {
                                    newScale = scaleX / zValue
                                } else {
                                    newScale = 1.0;
                                }
                            }
                            scaleImage(newScale, e);
                            setTransformOrigin();
                            window.onmousemove = null;
                       });
                    }
                }
            }]);

    })();
```

Use at HTML as

```
<image zoom  src="" ></image>
```

Comment: It would be great if you offered an example page of this working.  Also, looks like your solution is using jQuery, is there a version that is more AngularJS?